# Potential Issues Using cURL CLI and libcurl in multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl, slack-api

I am working on a Linux-based headless system for work that automatically runs a multithreaded C++ program that connects to various web services (Slack, AWS S3, etc.) for both upload and download of various files, and posting smaller JSON messages. We have a 5k-10k of these systems deployed with customers. There are times when all networking on the device appears to completely fail, and it's quite difficult to replicate this issue which up until now, has been chalked up to local network environment issues by my colleagues.

I've recently had time to dig into some of the application logs and it appears most curl errors (error code 6) stem from possible inability to resolve host (specifically, slack.com). I noticed also that much of the C++ code utilizes spawns child processes using cURL CLI which are all tied to the slack service utility, while other parts of the program utilize libcurl, namely AWS SDK C++ and smaller webservices for our own website.

TL:DR - individual cURL CLI child processes spawned by my C++ program appear to be interrupting all processes using libcurl when throwing SIGINT.

My questions are:

1. Are there any potential issues with using cURL CLI and libcurl in a multithreaded program such as this? It seems like the curl command failing on slack is sending SIGINT to everything using libcurl.
2. Am I better of moving everything to libcurl or is there a way to deal with the SIGINT without rewriting that whole section of code?
3. Any ideas or resources?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Signals, like SIGINT, are delivered to the entire process, not just to individual threads.

Comment: *It seems like the curl command failing on slack is sending SIGINT to everything using libcurl.*  Why would a `curl` command spawned by your process send `SIGINT` to anything?  There's absolutely no mention of `SIGINT` or any other signal on the `curl` man page at https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html  I'd say your first issue is to find where the `SIGINT` is really coming from.

Comment: Read this [CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.html) and [Common mistakes when using libcurl](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2021/09/27/common-mistakes-when-using-libcurl/)